# Error when reading XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am currently writing an XML writer/reader. I have it writing to the xml file, now I am attempting to read from it. However, when I do so the following error is thrown and I am not sure why:

`'>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 6, position 16. XML reader c#`

Please could someone shed some light on this for me?

The XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assignments>
  <assignment>
    <ModuleTitle>Internet Programming</ModuleTitle>
    <AssignmentTitle>Assignment 01</AssignmentTitle>
    <Date Given>11/02/2015</Date Given>
    <Date Due>20/02/2015</Date Due>
  </assignment>
</assignments>
```

UPDATE:

The problem was the fact that in some of my tag names I had spaces, which was causing the error.

Comment: _"when I do so the above error is thrown"_ Can you show the code that causes the error?

Comment: Remove the spaces on tags, instead `Date Given` use `DaveGiven`.

Comment: Ah thanks Felipe, the problem was the white spaces in the tag names. +1 thanks!

Comment: Are you just writing the XML via String concatenation ? If so I would use an XML API, so that you can't create the above in the first place (plus encoding and escaping will be correct)

Answer (score 3):

You have invalid spaces, the following will work:

```
XElement config = XElement.Parse (
@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assignments>
  <assignment>
    <ModuleTitle>Internet Programming</ModuleTitle>
    <AssignmentTitle>Assignment 01</AssignmentTitle>
    <DateGiven>11/02/2015</DateGiven>
    <DateDue>20/02/2015</DateDue>
  </assignment>
</assignments>");
```

Please note `DateGiven` and `DateDue`without spaces.

The spaces **are** the reason for the error as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`<Date Given>` is not a valid XML syntax. `Given` is supposed to be an attribute with a value, so it should look something like this: `<Date Given="true">`

Edit to be useful in the future: as @James mentioned, it is just a space in the tag name, which is also invalid in XML.

Comment: Or `<DateGiven>` which seems more likely

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. The problem was the fact that I had spaces in some of the tag names. Thanks anyway!